# How UWP apps deployed via provisioning package get update?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

In order to distribute our UWP app to the Windows 10 Enterprises, we created a provisioning package to deploy our app (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-packages).

How the app gets update in this case if we release one? Is the only option is to provide them a new provisioning package and previous version of the app must be uninstalled manually by them?

Comment: You could install the new version package directly, just making sure the version number is higher than the previous app. Or you will need to  uninstall previous app manually.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update your provisioning package, you need to make sure the version number of your new package is higher than the local installed package. So you can override the old package without uninstalling it.

If your project code need to be rolled back, you still need to make sure the package version number higher than the previous one.

When you need to uninstall the package manually, you may remember to save the user data to roaming settings. Or it cannot guarantee that your newly installed package includes the original user data.